# submit form with input field validation in react.js

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a simple validation form, where user is expected to input their zipcode and aadhar number. I should not be submitting form, if user has left any of these fields blank. I am using validator, which seems to be working well but it looks with onSubmit.. all three if blocks getting executed at once and form is getting submitted with first click.
However 2nd click onwards, alert inside last if block doesn't gets call.
But how can i achieve this with first submission:

```
import React,{useState, Fragment} from 'react'
import validator from 'validator'

const ValForm = () => {
   const [formData,setFormData]=useState({
        pinCode:'',
        aadhar:''
    })
    const [formError,setFormError]=useState({
        zipError:'',
        aadharError:''
    })
    const {pinCode,aadhar}=formData;
    const {zipError,aadharError}=formError;

    const onChange = e => {
        setFormData({...formData,[e.target.name]:e.target.value})
        setFormError({...formError,zipError:'',aadharError:''})    

    }
    const onSubmit = async e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (validator.isEmpty(pinCode)){
           // setFormError({...formError,zipError:"Please enter pin code."})
           setFormError(prevState=>{return{...prevState,zipError:"Please enter pin code."}} )
        }
        if (validator.isEmpty(aadhar)){
           setFormError(prevState=>{return{...prevState,aadharError:"Please enter aadhar number."}} )
        }

        if(zipError==='' && aadharError===''){
            alert("Form is good to submit.")
        }
    }

    return (
        <Fragment>
            <h1>Please make sure it's you only:</h1>
            <form onSubmit={e=>onSubmit(e)}> 
            <label>PinCode:</label>
            <br/>
            <input type="input" 
              placeholder="Enter your pin code" 
              name="pinCode"
              id="pinCode"
              value={pinCode}
              onChange={(e)=>onChange(e)}/>
            <br/>
            <div className="err_class">{zipError ? zipError : ''}</div>

            <label>Aadhar Number:</label>
            <br/>
            <input type="input" 
              placeholder="Enter your Aadhar number" 
              name="aadhar"
              id="aadhar"
              value={aadhar}
              onChange={(e)=>onChange(e)}/>
            <br/>
            <div className="err_class">{aadharError ? aadharError : ''}        </div>
            <br/>
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
          </form>

    </Fragment>
    )
}

export default ValForm
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
  const onSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (validator.isEmpty(pinCode)){
       // setFormError({...formError,zipError:"Please enter pin code."})
       setFormError(prevState=>{return{...prevState,zipError:"Please enter pin code."}} )
    }
    if (validator.isEmpty(aadhar)){
       setFormError(prevState=>{return{...prevState,aadharError:"Please enter aadhar number."}} )
    }

    if(!validator.isEmpty(pinCode) && !validator.isEmpty(aadhar)){
        alert("Form is good to submit.")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it helped, simple and good soln.. I have to do some field level validations as well, for that i wrote another function, which i am calling with onBlur and i put condition with if statement inside onSubmit , and it worked well..